# Is it possible in SQL to split the numbers by the delimiter and count them?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column in SQL table with a list of items like below: `99987995\|M99987995\|99987995\|`. I want to split the items by delimiter(/|) and then count the number of items. for example I will have 3 items from the list i.e `99987995, M99987995, 99987995`. Attached is also an image and what the result will look like. For every group in header 2, I want to count the number of items in header 3. Now header3 has some null/empty fields as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QtJH.jpg)

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT [header2] as Header, Cnt as [Number of items] from [table] t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT( [value]) Cnt FROM STRING_SPLIT( REPLACE( [header3], '\|', ','), ',')     
    )x
```

Comment: I edited the question with more details on the table

Comment: @SeanjeeWatara, from your image it looks like you have 0 items in group 'A', 2 items in group 'B' and 0 items in group 'C'. But why your expected result looks like A-2, B-1, C-15?

Comment: sorry about that, I made the necessary changes

Comment: @SeanjeeWatara, I edited my answer, try above code if it works for you